# Implementation of pthread multithreading and mutex

Tags: c, posix, pthreads

I am trying to implement a "proper" pthread multithreading program with pthread mutex. I want it to be as C-standard-conforming and POSIX-conforming as possible. The below is my implementation, any thoughts or bugs?:

`main.c`:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "common.h"


static char shared_string[512];
pthread_mutex_t my_mutex;


void* func_that_takes_params(void* tpl) {
    struct ThreadPayload* args = (struct ThreadPayload*)tpl;
    while (!should_stop) {
        // Let's add a bit of perturbation, but not too much
        usleep(1000 * 1000 - args->thread_id);
        if (pthread_mutex_lock(&my_mutex) != 0) {
            perror("pthread_mutex_lock()");
            continue;
        }
        sprintf(shared_string, "[%d] Message from caller: %s\n",
            args->thread_id, args->message);
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, shared_string, strlen(shared_string));
        if (pthread_mutex_unlock(&my_mutex) != 0) {
            perror("pthread_mutex_unlock()");
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    size_t* ret = malloc(sizeof(size_t));
    if (ret != NULL) {
        *ret = strlen(args->message);
    } else {
        perror("malloc()");
    }
    return (void*)ret;
}


int main(void) {
    install_signal_handler();
    should_stop = false;
    if (pthread_mutex_init(&my_mutex, NULL) != 0) {
        perror("pthread_mutex_init()");
        return 1;
    }

    size_t thread_count = sizeof(thread_payloads)/sizeof(thread_payloads[0]);

    pthread_t ths[thread_count];
    size_t started_threads;
    for (started_threads = 0; started_threads < thread_count; ++started_threads) {
        if (pthread_create(&ths[started_threads], NULL, func_that_takes_params,
            &thread_payloads[started_threads]) != 0) {
            perror("pthread_create()");
            --started_threads;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%d threads started\n", started_threads);
    for (int i = 0; i < started_threads; ++i) {
        size_t* ret = NULL;
        if (pthread_join(ths[i], (void**)&ret) != 0) {
            perror("pthread_join()");
            continue;
        }
        if (ret != NULL) {
            printf("ret: %u\n", *ret);
        } else {
            printf("ret is NULL\n");
        }
        free(ret);
    }
    if (pthread_mutex_destroy(&my_mutex) != 0) {
        perror("pthread_mutex_destroy()");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

- `common.h`

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t should_stop;

struct ThreadPayload {
    size_t thread_id;
    char* message;
};

static struct ThreadPayload thread_payloads[] = {
    {
        .thread_id = 0,
        .message = "This is a test message"
    }, {
        .thread_id = 1,
        .message = "This is also a test message"
    }, {
        .thread_id = 2,
        .message = "This is yet another a test message"
    }, {
        .thread_id = 3,
        .message = "Hello world!!"
    }, {
        .thread_id = 4,
        .message = "foobar"
    }, {
        .thread_id = 5,
        .message = "0xDEADBEEF"
    }, {
        .thread_id = 6,
        .message = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
    }, {
        .thread_id = 7,
        .message = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
    }
};

static void signal_handler(int signum) {
    char msg[] = "Signal [  ] caught\n";
    msg[8] = '0' + signum / 10;
    msg[9] = '0' + signum % 10;
    size_t len = sizeof(msg) - 1;
    size_t written = 0;
    while (written < len) {
        ssize_t ret = write(STDOUT_FILENO, msg + written, len - written);
        if (ret == -1) {
            perror("write()");
            break;
        }
        written += ret;
    }
    should_stop = true;
}

// This function calls abort() if fails
void install_signal_handler() {
    struct sigaction act;
    if (sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask) == -1) {
        perror("sigemptyset()");
        abort();
    }
    act.sa_handler = signal_handler;  
    act.sa_flags = 0;
    if (sigaction(SIGINT,  &act, 0) + sigaction(SIGABRT, &act, 0) +
        sigaction(SIGQUIT, &act, 0) + sigaction(SIGTERM, &act, 0) < 0) {
        perror("sigaction()");
        abort();
    }
}
```

- `Makefile`

```
CC = gcc
LIBS = -lpthread -lglib-2.0
OPTS = -O2 -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -Wc++-compat

main: main.out

main.out: main.c common.h
    $(CC) main.c -o main.out $(LIBS)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm *.out
```

Comment: Incorporating advice from an answer into the question violates the question-and-answer nature of this site.  You could post improved code as a new question, as an answer, or as a link to an external site - as described in [I improved my code based on the reviews. What next?](/help/someone-answers#help-post-body).  I have rolled back the edit, so the answers make sense again.

Answer (score 5):

> ... to be as C-standard-conforming and POSIX-conforming as possible.

**Enable more warnings**

Save time, enable more warnings to see more weaknesses.

I compiled with gcc and `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion` and saw these below warnings.  The format errors are especially egregious.  Not sure why my compilation caught those and yours did not.

```
//sprintf(shared_string, "[%d] Message from caller: %s\n",
//        args->thread_id, args->message);
sprintf(shared_string, "[%zu] Message from caller: %s\n",
        args->thread_id, args->message);
```

`-Wconversion` is a pesky, yet insightful option.  The 2nd & 3rd warnings, IMO, are noisy.

```
In function 'signal_handler':
warning: conversion from 'int' to 'char' may change value [-Wconversion]
   48 |     msg[8] = '0' + signum / 10;
      |              ^~~

warning: conversion from 'int' to 'char' may change value [-Wconversion]
   49 |     msg[9] = '0' + signum % 10;
      |              ^~~

warning: conversion to 'long unsigned int' from 'ssize_t' {aka 'long int'} may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
   58 |         written += ret;
      |                 ^~

In function 'func_that_takes_params':
warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 3 has type 'size_t' {aka 'long unsigned int'} [-Wformat=]
   93 |         sprintf(shared_string, "[%d] Message from caller: %s\n",
      |                                  ~^
      |                                   |
      |                                   int
      |                                  %ld
   94 |             args->thread_id, args->message);
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~        
      |                 |
      |                 size_t {aka long unsigned int}

In function 'main':
warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'size_t' {aka 'long unsigned int'} [-Wformat=]
  131 |     printf("%d threads started\n", started_threads);
      |             ~^                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |              |                     |
      |              int                   size_t {aka long unsigned int}
      |             %ld

warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'int' and 'size_t' {aka 'long unsigned int'} [-Wsign-compare]
  132 |     for (int i = 0; i < started_threads; ++i) {
      |                       ^
warning: format '%u' expects argument of type 'unsigned int', but argument 2 has type 'size_t' {aka 'long unsigned int'} [-Wformat=]
  139 |             printf("ret: %u\n", *ret);
      |                          ~^     ~~~~
      |                           |     |
      |                           |     size_t {aka long unsigned int}
      |                           unsigned int
      |                          %lu
```

**Avoid `signum` out of range**

If `signum < 0` or more than 99 leads to woes.  Maybe:

```
static void signal_handler(int signum) {
  signum = (int) ((unsigned) signum % 100u);  // Add
  char msg[] = "Signal [  ] caught\n";
  msg[8] = '0' + signum / 10; 
  msg[9] = '0' + signum % 10;
```

Note `signum %= 100;` does not ensure positivity.

**Maybe `const`?**

Perhaps a little tighter control with `const`.

```
struct ThreadPayload {
  size_t thread_id;
  // char* message;
  const char* message;
};
```

**Uncommon to put function definitions in a .h file**

More common to create a `common.c` with function/object *definitions* and companion `common.h` with function/object *declarations*, typedefs, ....

---

**Minor**

- Cast not needed in `return (void*)ret;`.  I suppose cast is there for "-Wc++-compat".

---

**`sprintf()`**

A common feedback is to use `snprintf()` vs. `sprintf()`

```
// sprintf(shared_string, ...
snprintf(shared_string, sizeof shared_string, ...
```

To me, unless the return value is checked, that trades one problem for another.

Code could test as below.  Your call as to what level of checking you want.

```
int len = snprintf(shared_string, sizeof shared_string, ...
if (len < 0 || (unsigned) len >= sizeof shared_string) {
  ; //Handle error
}
// Or
int len = snprintf(shared_string, sizeof shared_string, ...
assert(len >= 0 && (unsigned) len < sizeof shared_string);
(void) len; // To quiet warning when not compiled in DEBUG mode.
```

Comment: On "Enable more warnings", Do you also use gcc for this?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind "Do you also use gcc for this?" --> Answer has "I compiled with gcc ...".

Comment: Emmm sorry for missing your info. I just reviewed my code, seems I forget to append `$(OPTS)` to the compilation command. I can see a lot of warnings after appending it.

Comment: I asked a few questions on CodeReview before. There is one thing that I have never been sure--after reading the answers, am I supposed to append my entire revised code (or some tiny revised snippets) back to my original post? Or should I just leave it as it is?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind, Edit both questions with _appended_ info linking the two together.  Might want to add lessons learned.

Comment: @D.J.Elkind, now that l lot of the small stuff is reviewed, we can get to the deeper issues.  But that takes more time.

Comment: Does `-Wc++-compat` really require a cast for conversion from object pointer to `void*`?  That's fine in C++ as it is in C; it's only the opposite direction that should require a cast.

Comment: On `sprintf` vs `snprintf`, what is the recommended way to handle error? `perror("sprintf()")`? Also, in my case, all c-strings are guaranteed to be null-terminated, so I supposed `snprintf()` doesn't offer anything extra?

Comment: @TobySpeight I suspect you are correct about `-Wc++-compat`.  I do not use it nor recommend its use and so don't spend effort optimizing it.

Comment: @D.J.Elkind "recommended way to handle error" is _very_ dependent on your overall design.  With low-level functions, I recommend to detect and report.  With higher level code, it depends on coding goals.

Comment: @D.J.Elkind "in my case, all c-strings are guaranteed to be null-terminated," is unclear.  _All_ C-strings are null-terminated by definition, else it is not a _string_.  The `sprintf()` vs. `snprintf()` is an issue of length and buffer size, not _null character_ and how to handle any error.

Comment: On "With low-level functions, I recommend to detect and report. With higher level code, it depends on coding goals." -> my real question is, if functions as simple/low-level as `sprintf()`/`snprinf()` failed, what else can be done? Let's say I can go as low-level as possible and the issue is detected (e.g., `sprintf()` returns a small value), what should be done next?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind In the case of `sprintf(shared_string, "[%d] Message from caller: %s\n", args->thread_id, args->message);`, a pedantic  recommendation: `int len = snprintf(shared_string, sizeof shared_string, "[%d] Message from caller: %s\n", args->thread_id, args->message); if (len < 0 || (unsigned) len >= sizeof shared_string) { perror("some message"); return NULL; }`.

Comment: this will be a bit paranoid though--it means that I need to check every `printf()` as well.

Comment: `snprintf()` setting `errno` is a POSIX behaviour, so using `perror()` would be wrong elsewhere - a portability issue.

Comment: @TobySpeight What _wrong_ about `perror()`, even if `errno == 0`?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind "means that I need to check every printf() " --> `printf()` does not readily have a _too long an output_ issue that `snprintf()` is trying to avoid.   IAC, you asked, "what else can be done?".  [Comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/284635/implementation-of-pthread-multithreading-and-mutex/284657?noredirect=1#comment566392_284657) provides a possibility.   Sorry you find it [unacceptable](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/284635/implementation-of-pthread-multithreading-and-mutex/284657?noredirect=1#comment566394_284657).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica got your *too long an output* point. My thought is that C is fast partly because we left many cases unchecked/undefined. If we apply the same logic to all the array access, it can make C safer but slower. In this particular case, the buffer's size and c-strings are pre-defined, all possible c-strings are much shorter than the buffer size, so I am of the view that adding an extra check is not needed.

Comment: @chux, if we use `perror()` on non-POSIX systems, its output may be misleading to the user (typically writing "No error" or similar).  That's what's wrong there.  If this code targets only systems where failed `sprintf()` sets `errno`, then using `perror()` will work, correctly indicating the error.

Answer (score 3):

## C11 has optional support for threads and mutexes

> I want it to be as C-standard-conforming and POSIX-conforming as possible.

C11 introduced support for [threads and mutexes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread), avoiding the need to rely on POSIX functions. The only drawback is that this an optional part of the C11 standard, and some compilers still don't implement it.

## About mixing `write()`, `printf()` and mutexes

Calls to `write()` might be atomic, depending on whether you are writing to a file, socket, pipe or something else, and depending on the amount you are writing. Therefore, you might not need to lock a mutex around calls to it if you are just writing single lines to a terminal. However, the threads you start are not the only ones that are trying to write to standard output: you still use `printf()` on the main thread. There is no guarantee that every line printed using `printf()` will be done so using a single `write()` call. Thus, the output from the threads could be mixed in an incorrect way with the output from the main thread.

You could also consider using only `printf()` in your code to write anything. This might also be enough, since the standard library might internally take a lock around each `printf()` call (see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23586682/how-to-use-printf-in-multiple-threads)). However, again this only works if you don't mix it with threads that call `write()`.

The safest option however is to always use a mutex when writing to standard ouptut. That way, you can also mix and match `write()` and `printf()` however you like. However, taking a mutex in a signal handler is problematic: what if the thread that got the signal already had locked the mutex? Trying to lock it again from within the signal handler will cause a deadlock. You could use `pthread_mutex_trylock()` in this case to do a best effort attempt at keeping the output synchronized.

Comment: On C11's thread support, it is great to know that. I am not aware of this at the time of preparing this implementation. On the `write()`'s atomicity, do you have any reference? My understanding is that POSIX only requires `write()` to be re-entrant, but it can be interrupted (and thus not atomic).

Comment: The short answer is "it depends". I've made use of `write()`s atomicity in some contexts before, but it was platform dependent, so in general it's indeed better to not assume anything and just use a mutex everywhere to synchronize output to `stdout`.

Answer (score 3):

**Undefined behaviour:**

```
perror("write()");
```

`perror()` is [async-signal-unsafe](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html). As such, is it not possible to call it safely in a signal handler without invoking undefined behavior.

**Reduce duplication:**

```
/*
struct ThreadPayload {
    size_t thread_id;
    char* message;
}; 

static struct ThreadPayload thread_payloads[] = {
{
        .thread_id = 0,
        .message = "This is a test message"
}
*/

#define DEF(_id, _msg) \
        { .thread_id = _id, .message = _msg } 

struct ThreadPayload {
    size_t thread_id;
    char* message;
} static thread_payloads[] = { 
    DEF (0, "This is a test message"),
    DEF (1, "DEADBEEF"),
    ...
};

/* Could undef it here, should you so desire. */
#undef DEF
```

**Use more `const`:**

```
/* In signal_handler() */
struct ThreadPayload {
   // size_t thread_id;
   // char* message;
   const size_t thread_id; /* We could do with unsigned here. */
   const char *const message;
};

// size_t len = sizeof(msg) - 1;
const size_t len = sizeof msg - 1;

/* In main() */
// size_t thread_count = sizeof(thread_payloads)/sizeof(thread_payloads[0]);
   const size_t thread_count = sizeof(thread_payloads)/sizeof(thread_payloads[0]);
```

Why call `abort()` if an error occurs? Does `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` not suffice?

The looping around `write()` in `signal_handler()` should be a separate function.

**Avoid using magic numbers:**

```
static char shared_string[512];
```

We need a defined constant for `512`.

**Avoid cluttering the code with redundant casts:**

```
// struct ThreadPayload* args = (struct ThreadPayload*)tpl;
   struct ThreadPayload* args = tpl;

// return (void*)ret;
   return ret;
```

**Reduce scope:**

```
/*
size_t started_threads;
    for (started_threads = 0; started_threads < thread_count; ++started_threads) {
*/

for (size_t started_threads ...)
```

**Avoid ignoring compiler warnings:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < started_threads; ++i) {
```

The type of `started_threads` is `size_t`. There must have been a warning along the lines of:

```
Warning: Comparison between signed and unsigned or so.
```

If the compiler didn't complain, enable more warnings.

In `func_that_takes_params()`, check the return value of `write()`.

Comment: The first issue looks the most interesting--what is the alternative way to handle the error on `write()`?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind You can also write your own re-entrancy safe log utils.

Comment: my version will be using `write()` to log errors that occur to `write()` lol?

Comment: Indeed, so there's no guarantee that a further call to `write()` would succeed. I wouldn't bother about reporting an error to stderr.